# Is $X^p - t\in \mathbb{F}_p (t) [X]$ separable over $\mathbb{F}_p (t)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

> Is $X^p - t\in \mathbb{F}_p (t) [X]$ separable over $\mathbb{F}_p (t)$?

I am trying to understand what are in these two structures. My thought is that, if we look at the derivative of $X^p - t$, we get $p X^{p-1}$. In $\mathbb{F}_p (t)$, $p=0$. (Not sure about this). So $\gcd(X^p - t, pX^{p-1})\ne 1$. As a result, $X^p -t$ has multiple roots, thus not separable.

Is this correct? If it is, is there any "better" proof? If this is really trivial then never mind. Thank you.

**Update:** I am asking for a proof verification because most of the proofs I see online use Gauss lemma and Eisenstein criterion.

Comment: yes it's correct !

Comment: @Surb Sweet. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure those proofs you're seeing online are proving that $X^p-t$ is not separable?  It sounds from your description like they're instead proving that $X^p-t$ is irreducible.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, you are right! I was being stupid -_- haha. On the other hand, would you mind explaining why $p=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$? The way I think about it is that, in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $[p]_p=[0]_0$. I am not totally convinced because $\mathbb{F}_p$ is just some random finite field with some operation that is yet to be defined.

Comment: The field $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with the multiplication and addition induced from $\mathbb{Z}$. Then is is clear that $p=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct. Another way to see this would be to observe that if $ \alpha $ is a root of $ X^p - t $ in some extension of $ \mathbb{F}_p(t) $, then this polynomial can be written as $ X^p - \alpha^p = (X - \alpha)^p $, so it is clearly inseparable.